# Hibernate LockMode expected behavior

Tags: spring, hibernate, concurrency

```
@Repository
public class MyClass{
    public int myFunction(Integer id){
        Record x = recordDao.get(id,LockMode.UPGRADE);
        int d = x.getProp();
        x.setProp(d+1);
        recordDao.update(z);
    }
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class MyOtherClass{

    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    public void myOtherFnx(Integer id){
        try{
            myClass.myFunction(id);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

What happens when `new MyOtherClass().myOtherFnx(3)` was invoked at same time but at separate request/transactions.
I tried creating runnables and invoke `myOtherFunx` on separate threads to simulate concurrency. I was expecting to get RuntimeException but 
so far I haven't notice getting any runtime exception even if i increase the threads running `myOtherFunx` to 50. 
Can you explain to me why this happens? Or is my assumption that a runtime exception will occur. The case when I am expecting a runtime exception
is when multiple threads invoke `myClass.myFunction(3)` and the Record object retrieved on these threads are the same, let's say
id=3,prop=4. Since one of them gets the lock first, when threads try to update the record only one should update and others will throw exception since I am catching all Exception.

Answer (score 1):

The first Thread will acquire the lock, and release it on commit or rollback.

While the first Thread is doing its work, the rest of threads will **wait** for the lock to be released.

After the lock has been released, the next Thread will acquire it, do the updates, commit, and so on...

If you want to get an exception, you will have to use the LockMode `UPGRADE_NOWAIT`.